# Android: change display content when wipe on the screen

Tags: android

I want to change the lower half of the screen when the user wipes with the finger, but got no idea how to start. The upper half with sone TextViews should stay fixed.
Do I need more then one activity, or can I just change the layout portion on the lower half?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need more then one activity

No.

> or can I just change the layout portion on the lower half?

Yes. Drop my [`ViewSwiper`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-viewswiper) into your layout in the lower half. Give the `ViewSwiper` child widgets/containers. `ViewSwiper` will handle the swipe gesture and flipping between the children for you.

Comment: Thanks, great, very simple to use. Compiles with warnings, but works. Is there an option that the views move smoothly with the gesture (like the htc sense home screen)?

Comment: thanks for giving valuable hints to a newbie :) That scrolls smoothely indeed. Is there a way to let the horizontalScrollView "snap" to certain position when the gesture is stopped and to have an event fired then?

Comment: @elsni: Not that I'm aware of.